# Xlib is old? do developers use xlib framework? It was developed in 1985

Tags: qt, gtk, xlib, motif

Does anyone still use it? xlib seems such an old framework?

what other major similar software is used instead of this old xlib?

**What is used instead of xlib?**

Comment: The question is too broad.

Comment: As long as X11 is used, xlib will be used as well. However, one rarely uses it directly but uses a Toolkit such as Qt or Gtk+ instead (which in turn interface with xlib).

Comment: @n.m.: yeah... It is also primarily opinion based as well as off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XLib is still used in most X11 toolkits however, there is a newer library called XCB that is slowly replacing it. XCB is lower level than XLib and allows you to minimise the number of round-trips to the X server leading to lower latency.

http://xcb.freedesktop.org/